# Highlight multiple cells according to list in Libreoffice Calc

Tags: libreoffice, r

I am new users of Calc. I would like to highlight different cells that have different Id. My aim is to copy the hole row of each of them. Here is an example what I would like to do.

```
Id Name Age  Affiliate
1  X     23  DD
2  Y     33  DD
3  G     46  SS
4  Z     19  TY
5  W     80  CE
```

and my list is

```
id
6 
2
3
5
7
```

After that I would like to reorder them according to the 1st table. I also tried to do it with R without success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the functions allowing to combine tables and lists in LibreOffice is `Vlookup` - vertical lookup. What it does is to take a value, like the number 6 in your list, search in the first column of the table and return one of the values from the corresponding rows in the table.

Thus `Vlookup` definition includes:
- the text or value to search for (single value)
- the range of cells (table) where to search that value - the function only looks into the first column of that range
- the number of the column desired as a result
- a logical value that defines if the original table is sorted (best left to 0)

The range of cells containing the table should be defined through absolute references (using the "$" sign in front of the cell references). As an example, I have used the same formula on columns F, G and H, but changed the recovered column number:

[image: Vlook example and formula]

R gives a lot more flexibility and speed for the same operations but on short lists and with the data at hand Vlookup is pretty powerful. In R, `merge.data.frame` is one of the functions that can be used for combining tables (data frames) by using a given column. If the table is in a data frame called `tb` and the list is another data frame called `ids`, merging the two would be done by:

```
>merged <- merge.data.frame(ids, tb, by.x="id", by.y="Id", sort=F)
> merged
id Name Age Affiliate
1  2    Y  33        DD
2  3    G  46        SS
3  5    W  80        CE
```

The names of the columns used to merge the tables are "id" and "Id".

Comment: Thank you a lot. It absolutely right. I looked more in R and I could manage by using match. Concerning Calc. I tried to use COUNTIF and conditional formating. After that, I learned the function Vlookup but I could not figure it out. But here you well explain it. Now I'm aware a third method. Thank you again

Comment: You're very welcome. If only the Vlookup function was more intuitive ... If then answer is good, you can mark it as a good answer so that the question does not appear any more in the "unanswered" section.Thank you.